# Entity Model for Qt?

Tags: qt, data-modeling

Is there any program or easy process to take a database and build a model based off Qt around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing the reverse and I am happy with the results. I have used QDjango to build code, and have it build the database around that model.